# XUL get current tab index number

Tags: firefox, xul

i wanted to know how can i get the index of the current tab with xul.
I've this to create and save the current index of a new created tab:

Some code:

```
button.indexTabs = gBrowser.addTab(askUrl);         
button.newTabBrowser = gBrowser.getBrowserForTab(button.indexTabs);
```

How can i get the index of the actual current tab (created or not)?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`gBrowser.tabContainer.selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XUL/tabs#p-selectedIndex) to get the index of selected tab. You can also find the selected tab directly by [`gBrowser.selectedTab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tabbrowser#p-selectedTab)

Note that in Javascript module (or in SeaMonkey) you don't have access to gBrowser. You will have to find the browser XUL window by [`getMostRecentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator#getMostRecentWindow%28%29) and look for element with id `content`. This element corresponds to gBrowser.